# Unknown issue in C# when using Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a code that gets a line of text from raw.githubusercontent.com

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(getargs[1]);
using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (Stream content = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(content))
{
    string strCntent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] plgnCntn;
    plgnCntn = strCntent.Split('(', ')', ':', ',');
    if (plgnCntn[0] != "validplgn")
    {
        newln("Plgn couldn't be installed. Not validated.");
    }
    else
    {
        string dmy = plgnCntn[1];
        dummy = dmy.Split('-');
        install_id = Convert.ToInt32(dummy[1]);
        dummy = plgnCntn[2].Split('-');
        install_plgn_nme = dummy[1];
        dummy = plgnCntn[3].Split('-');
        install_cmmd = dummy[1];
        plgnbyID.Add(install_id, install_plgn_nme);
        plgncmds.Add(install_plgn_nme, install_cmmd);
        inverseplgncmds.Add(install_cmmd, install_plgn_nme);
        plgnparse.Add(install_plgn_nme, plgnCntn[4]);
    }
}
```

And all seems fine, the program gets the data, i'm testing with

> "validplgn(id-0001,plgn_nme-plgn,cmmd-plgninfo):{ln-This plugin has been downloaded from the creator's GitHub;hlp-hlp}"

When it gets the data, it splits it in

> "validplgn", "id-0001", "plgn_nme-plgn", "cmmd-plgninfo", "{ln-This plugin has been downloaded from the creator's GitHub;hlp-hlp}"

It is supposed to test if [0] == "validplgn", saves all the data in dictionaries. When all of this data is saved, the program continues running and checking for commands in a loop. Basically detecting what I put on the textbox, checking IF statements and giving answers, when the content in the textbox doesn't match with any command, it writes:

> "Command wasn't recognized. Please type hlp".

The problem comes, i think, in this code:

```
else if (plgncmds.ContainsValue(inp))
{
    string plgnnme;
    string toparse;
    string[] splitparse = {};
    int arglength;
    inverseplgncmds.TryGetValue(inp, out plgnnme);
    plgnparse.TryGetValue(plgnnme, out toparse);
    splitparse = toparse.Split(';');
    arglength = splitparse.Length;
    foreach (string statement in splitparse)
    {
        string[] dmmy = statement.Split('-');
    ...
```

At the final of the checker loop, tests if the unknown command to the client matches with any downloaded command in:

> else if (plgncmds.ContainsValue(inp))

So, when i input "plgninfo", that is the text that executes this code:

> {ln-This plugin has been downloaded from the creator's GitHub;hlp-hlp}
>   It was declared before, when "cmmd-plgninfo", was splitted and saved the plgninfo part. Now this code gets the key on the dictionary using the command (plgninfo), but it doesn't display anything. And thats the problem. It should print "This plugin has been downloaded from the creator's GitHub" and show program help for the command "hlp". but nothing, I have ReSharper 9 in VS 2013 and any issue is thrown, just nothing happens.

I hope theres a way to fix.
Thanks.

Comment: You have a lot of information, and no clear definition of what your issue is. Is there an error message or exception?

Comment: No, there isn't. I don't have any error message, it didn't crash, any exception... It's just doing what i explained up there. That's why I need the help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do more debugging. Step through your code with a debugger, inspect every variable's value and see if/when they have a value different than what you would expect.